# Facing issue while file uploading in casperjs

Tags: javascript, casperjs, slimerjs

I am facing problem while uploading a file using casperjs. and below is the link of the site:http://207.140.168.200/login.R
and below is the HTML content

```
<div id="collapse-file-upload" class="panel-collapse in" data-colwidth="2" style="height: auto;">
<img class="panel-shadow right" width="5px" height="105" src="/img/left_bordergray.png">
<div class="panel-body" style="height: 105px;">
<div id="file-upload-div" class="widget-vsize">
<div id="file-upload-wrapper">
<div id="file-upload-controls" class="btn-group-sm">
<input id="file" type="file" multiple="" style="display: inline;">
<span class="checkbox" style="display: inline-block; padding-top: 6px;">
<label>
<input id="upload-to-notebook" type="checkbox">
<span>Upload to notebook</span>
</label>
</span>
<button id="upload-submit" class="btn btn-default-ext" style="float: right;width: 33px;" type="submit">
<i class="icon-upload-alt"></i>
</button>
<div class="progress" style="display:none">
<div id="progress-bar" class="progress-bar" style="width: 0%" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuenow="0" role="progressbar">   
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="file-upload-results-row">
<div id="file-upload-results-scroller">
<div id="file-upload-results"> </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

and below is the casperjs code which i am using for automation

```
casper.then(function(){
casper.evaluate(function () {
    var element = document.getElementById('file');
    this.sendKeys(element, '/home/prateek/Download/Notebook 1.R');
    this.wait(3000)
});
this.click({ type : 'css' , path : '#upload-submit'});
this.echo('file has been uploaded')
});
```

It is not at all selecting the file from that location.Note that i am not running it headless, so that i can see all the operation going on

Comment: @Darren Cook, do you know anything about the above issue

Comment: @Artjom B, can you look into the above problem.

Answer (score 0):

After so many months found the solution and hence posting the solution. I know its kind weird to answer my question but i found the solution hence going forward and posting answer

Where 'filename' is location of the file which is going to be uploaded

```
casper.then(function () {
        this.evaluate(function (fileName) {
            __utils__.findOne('input[type="file"]').setAttribute('value', fileName)
        }, {fileName: fileName});
        this.page.uploadFile('input[type="file"]', fileName);
        console.log('Selecting a file');
    });
    casper.then(function () {
        casper.evaluate(function () {
            $('#upload-to-notebook').click();
        });
        console.log("Clicking on Upload to notebook check box");
        this.click(x(".//*[@id='upload-submit']"));
        console.log("Clicking on Submit icon");
    });
```